# MVC / .NET Root URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

In my layout page, I have:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My understanding is that this should not be altered when it is sent to the client. However, when I set up the website as a virtual application under a "myapp" folder in IIS, the HTML is:

```
<link href="/myapp/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'm a bit confused as I had thought I would need to change these URLs to:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">
```

in order for this to work correctly.

So do I need to use URL.Content to get the correct root URL of the app/website, or can I just put tildes into the actual HTML src + href elements, and assume it will be outputted correctly by IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of ASP.NET MVC version 4 (or actually Razor version 2), the tilde links are essentially shortcuts to `Url.Content(..)`.

Answer (score -2):

You actually answered your own question. Yes, you should use Url.Content() for your relative paths. A simple tilde in front of relative paths are only parsed in the client's browser,which treats all URL's under the http://www.foo.com/ as a single domain, so will try to look for resources at http://www.foo.com/ and not http://www.foo.com/myapp/.

Comment: "A simple tilde in front of relative paths are only parsed in the client's browser"; This is not true as they are rendered by Razor.

Comment: Test it. I have found it to be the case.

Comment: Have you found that result while testing in ASP.NET MVC 4 and Razor 2 as well? They should be rendered (ie not visible in the rendered code).

Comment: I will go and test again. Don't want to give people wrong information.